# Orderby menu_order doesn't work

Tags: wp-query

My code is:

```
$sliders = new WP_Query(array('post_type' => 'sliders', 'showposts' => '10', 'orderby' => 'menu_order', 'order' => 'ASC', 'countries'=> 'Default', 'supress_filters' => true, 'meta_query' => array(
```

But  wordpress orderby post_date :(

```
 [query] => Array
    (
        [post_type] => sliders
        [showposts] => 10
        [orderby] => menu_order
        [order] => ASC
        [countries] => ES
        [supress_filters] => 1
        [meta_query] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [key] => _sectors
                        [value] => 540
                        [compare] => IN
                    )

            )

    )

[request] =>  SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS  wp_posts.* FROM wp_posts  INNER JOIN wp_term_relationships ON (wp_posts.ID = wp_term_relationships.object_id) INNER JOIN wp_postmeta ON (wp_posts.ID = wp_postmeta.post_id)  JOIN wp_icl_translations t ON wp_posts.ID = t.element_id
                    AND t.element_type = 'post_sliders' JOIN wp_icl_languages l ON t.language_code=l.code AND l.active=1 WHERE 1=1  AND ( wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id IN (16) ) AND wp_posts.post_type = 'sliders' AND (wp_posts.post_status = 'publish' OR wp_posts.post_status = 'private') AND ( (wp_postmeta.meta_key = '_sectors' AND CAST(wp_postmeta.meta_value AS CHAR) IN ('540')) ) AND t.language_code='es' GROUP BY wp_posts.ID ORDER BY wp_posts.post_date DESC LIMIT 0, 10
```

Comment: I doubt this is your problem but both `showposts` and and `{tax}` (where you use `'countries'`) are deprecated. Use `posts_per_page` and a `tax_query` instead.

Answer (score 6):

Use this instead. It worked for me

```
'sort_column' => 'menu_order'
```

Comment: This answer is really underrated. This worked perfectly

Comment: I'm glad it worked for you. Thanks David

Answer (score 5):

First, it's `suppress_filters` with two P's.

Secondly, 'countries' => 'default' doesn't do anything in a normal query, so I suspect you have something else going on code-wise.

Third, when I do your query with this code

```
$sliders = new WP_Query(array('post_type' => 'sliders', 
'showposts' => '10', 
'orderby' => 'menu_order', 
'order' => 'ASC', 
'countries'=> 'Default', 
'suppress_filters' => true, 
'meta_query' => array( array(
    'key' => '_sectors',
    'value' => 540,
    'compare' => 'IN',
    ) ),
) );
```

I get this result:

`SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS  wp_posts.ID FROM wp_posts  INNER JOIN wp_postmeta ON (wp_posts.ID = wp_postmeta.post_id) WHERE 1=1  AND wp_posts.post_type = 'sliders' AND (wp_posts.post_status = 'publish' OR wp_posts.post_status = 'future' OR wp_posts.post_status = 'draft' OR wp_posts.post_status = 'pending' OR wp_posts.post_author = 1 AND wp_posts.post_status = 'private') AND ( (wp_postmeta.meta_key = '_sectors' AND CAST(wp_postmeta.meta_value AS CHAR) IN ('540')) ) GROUP BY wp_posts.ID ORDER BY wp_posts.menu_order ASC LIMIT 0, 10`

Notice that the order by menu order is correct.

Answer (score 3):

I think (could be wrong) the problem is only pages have menu_order. Also, when you registered the post_type did you set it to `'hierarchical' => true,` ?

Comment: How is this relevant to the question? Please post an explanation