# Display Post by menu order

Tags: posts, menus, loop

I want to display posts on my homepage. But I like to manage the posts using Wordpress Menu, so I can easily add, delete, and re-arrange the ordering of posts displayed in the homepage.

For Example:

I have 5 posts, POST1, POST2, POST3 and so on. I want to show POST4 and POST1 on my homepage. Instead of creating a custom loop, I want to use the Wordpress Menu, so all I have to do is to check POST4 and POST1 then add to menu, if I want the POST1 to be the first post in homepage all I have to do is to drag the POST1 above the POST4 then save, and that should do it. In my homepage, there should be POST1 and POST4 displayed.

This what I want to achieve.

Sorry if I don't have the code because I don't have an idea how to do this. Thanks.

Comment: Could you explain in detail what exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I edited my question, hope it makes more sense, sorry for poor English.

Comment: Are you using a static front page with a custom loop? Or is this the default blog index?

Comment: I am using static frontpage.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Orderby menu\_order doesn't work](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/56052/orderby-menu-order-doesnt-work)